# Q&A-Style Answering Own Question

Tags: discussion

Since the site is in beta, and the idea is to develop a core of high-quality questions: should we be posting what we think are good questions which we ourselves know the answers to?

For example, I could pose a hypothetical problem (or an old problem) which I have already solved, and I anticipate many others will face in the future, and present my own solution as an answer. Is this frowned upon or encouraged?

Comment: Go for it, it is encouraged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far [as I understand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), posting questions Q&A style is encouraged. That's probably why now you can even post the question and the answer at the same time through the website interface.

I was doing it myself here, and for one of two questions, there was a [better answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/69/191) proposed, which in my opinion is really cool.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar concern about the "high-quality-questions", so I asked about what to do with the example questions posted in the definition phase. I asked in Area 51 meta and an [answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26843/171292) suggest posting the example questions is fine.

Posting and answering your own question is not frowned upon but  the [tour page](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/tour) says:

> - Specific issues with bioinformatics
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

So if it a hypothetical problem it is not a good question for the site.

Comment: Posting and answering your own question is [actively encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/203101), not just not frowned upon. The tour guidelines (which are basically the same for all SE sites) are trying to avoid open ended hypothetical stuff. A specific problem for which you have the answer should be fine.